# Deploying multiple contracts with web3js 1.0 at once

Tags: contract-development, web3js, nodejs

I'm new to Nodejs and Ethereum so I apologize in advance for any obvious mistakes.

I want to deploy multiple contracts in advance to have addresses ready when they are needed.

I use this to deploy the contract:

```
depositContract.deploy({
    data: contractCode,

})
.send({
    from: ownerAddress,
    gas: 4000000,
    gasPrice: gasPrice,
}, function (error, transactionHash) {

    if(error) console.log(error);

    console.log('HASH');
    console.log(transactionHash);

})
```

which works fine so far if I only deploy one contract. If I try to deploy multiple ones with a for loop I get the error:

```
Error: Returned error: known transaction:
```

Does anyone know how to solve this?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case anyone ever stumbles upon this problem this is the solution:
the nonce has to be increased for every deployed contract

```
web3.eth.getTransactionCount(senderAddress)
.then(nonce => {

    web3.eth.personal.unlockAccount(senderAddress, password)
        .then(() => {

        for (let i = 0; i < amountOfContractsToBeSendOut; i++) {; 

            let contract = new web3.eth.Contract(contractABI);

            contract.deploy({
                data: contractByteCode
            })
                .send({
                    from: senderAddress,
                    gas: (500000),
                    gasPrice: 5000000000,
                    nonce: nonce
                }, function (error, transactionHash) {

                    if(error) {

                        console.error(error)
                    }

                })
                .on('transactionHash', (transactionHash) => console.log(transactionHash))
                .on('receipt',  (receipt) => {

                    console.log(receipt)
                })
                .on('error', error => console.error(error))


            nonce++; //important!
            }

        })

});
```